# Report Book printing 97 unwanted copies

Tags: jasper-reports

**Current state:** Report book that prints 20680 pages

**The issue:** Report book is printing 98 times a report-element designated in the Content section (I've actually done the math)

**Rundown:**
Prototype_V2.jrxml (content report) --- report which has three subreports, all connected to the main by a single parameter
When compiled and run, this .jrxml produces 211 pages of various content, in other words, working 100% as the designer intended

Book_V3.jrxml  (book report)--- latest "version" of the report book template (green wave template) that ought to incorporate a ToC (primarily) and cover pages (secondary)

**I've tried:**

1. Putting for some unearthly reason the content report inside the cover element of the book report. Result: only prints once, but ToC is all messed up.(It's indexing literally every page of the content report, therefore diminishing its' purpose)
2. Various report evaluation times for the content report inside the "Content" section. Result: Only on evaluation time "Report", does the element print, but it prints itself 98 times, 97 more than wanted.Otherwise, it won't even print.
3. I've tried, and failed to, add parameters between the Book and its' content report. For some reason, they just don't see each other at all.
4. I've tried giving the book report dataset empty rows, and not actual rows from the MySQL from which I'm getting the data, but then it won't print a thing. ("Document is empty" screen)
5. Cut out the subreports from the content report so I was left with a 6 page skeleton, and still the book report printed 98x6+3 pages. Ridiculous

**The expectation:**

Report Book with one page for front cover, as many pages as needed for ToC with proper grouping (and not linking from the ToC to each separate page of a report), ONE PRINT OF content report (which is already designed and tuned), and one page for back cover...

*I know I haven't deliberately told the bastard to print one extra content report, much less 97 extra...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved:

***1.*** The 97 + 1 copies were produced because, unknowingly, I entered the same query for the book report as it is in the content report (98 is actually the number of unique groups my content report generated). Issue resolved with providing a KISS query of "select 1;" to the book dataset (because I'm not using the book for anything other than ToC and customization of cover pages)

*((Why having the same query for book and content report produced a multiplication of this magnitude is still unknown to me, but the important thing is that it's no longer an issue))*

***2.*** ToC issue of every page being indexed resolved when I realized that content report generated a unique bookmark for every page of print, regardless of whether it is the first page of the subgroup or not.

Issue resolved with addition of a second text field underneath the first for both of my groups (of same size,color,font...) that has "print repeated values" flag checked off, and that second field being bookmarked and referenced.

This way content report still prints visually on every page both group names but the book report is referencing the "other" text field, that prints only on first occurence, for its' ToC.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future struggling with similar issues.